# c++ function name not found if it overloads a c function name?

Tags: c++, c, linker, name-mangling

I was trying to override a C-style function (`func`) in a library with a C++ style function accepting different arguments, as the code below demonstrates.

I compiled test.cpp into a shared library libtest.so, and compiled main.cpp and linked it with the libtest.so library. This all works, upto the linking step, where I get
`undefined reference to 'func(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'`.

Can someone explain me why the linker cannot resolve the C++ function? I checked with nm that both functions are indeed in the library. The linker error occurs both with intel and g++ compilers.

test.h:

```
extern "C" {
int func( char* str, int size  );
}
#include <string>
int func( std::string str );
```

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "test.h"

int func( char *buf, int size )
{
   return snprintf( buf, size, "c-style func" );
}

int func( std::string& str )
{
    str = "c++-style func";
    return str.size();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
   char buf[1024];
   func( buf, 1024 );
   std::cout << buf << "\n";

   std::string str;
   func( str );
   std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

Comment: C++ function definition isn't visible to main.

Comment: One of my big complaints with C++: It's hard for the programmer to work out which overloaded function will be called, and you don't get warned until link time that something is wrong (and then it's gibberish).

Comment: @Matt Joiner: that's an implementation problem, not a C++ problem. The compiler WILL know before linking which declaration was chosen in each case. The linker should be able to demangle any C++ symbol, or else the IDE should do so.

Comment: @MSalters: Sure it's an implementation problem. So why isn't it fixed? C++ has been around for 25 years. It's barely usable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared the function in `test.h` as `int func(std::string)`, but defined it in `test.cpp` as `int func(std::string &)`.  See the difference?